# Set content type to HTML for lost password email only

Tags: password, html-email

Is there a way to change the content type for *only* the password reset email?

I have a custom HTML template for it, and have set wp_mail_content_type to text/html and am applying the template with a filter on retrieve_password_message. That all works fine and I get an HTML email for it, but I’m having a hard time figuring out where/how to reset wp_mail_content_type since I’m not actually calling wp_mail() anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT - here’s the code I’m using.

This is the function that changes the content type:

```
function xxx_wp_email_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'xxx_wp_email_content_type' );
```

And here’s the function that changes the email itself:

```
function xxx_wp_retrieve_password_message( $content, $key ) {
    ob_start();

    $email_subject = xxx_wp_retrieve_password_title();

    include( 'templates/email_header.php' );
    include( 'templates/lost_password_email.php' );
    include( 'templates/email_footer.php' );

    $message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_message', 'xxx_wp_retrieve_password_message', 10, 2 );
```

Typically I’d add a `remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'xxx_wp_email_content_type' );` after a call to `wp_mail()`, but there isn’t one here.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code and how you're using the filters?

Comment: Did not quite follow. Why do you need to reset the wp_mail_content_type, is it because you want other emails to send as text only?

Comment: @signal2013 Yes, the only one I want to send as HTML is the password reset email.

Comment: @phatskat Code has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you implemented the hook something like this:

```
function wp_set_html_mail_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wp_set_html_mail_content_type' );
```

More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_content_type

Did you need to reset the content type at a later point?

---

** UPDATE: try intercept it with a global variable:

```
function xxx_wp_email_content_type() {
    if($GLOBALS["use_html_content_type"]){
        return 'text/html';
    }else{
        return 'text/plain';
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'xxx_wp_email_content_type' );

function xxx_wp_retrieve_password_message( $content, $key ) {
    ob_start();

    $GLOBALS["use_html_content_type"] = TRUE;

    $email_subject = xxx_wp_retrieve_password_title();

    include( 'templates/email_header.php' );
    include( 'templates/lost_password_email.php' );
    include( 'templates/email_footer.php' );

    $message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_message', 'xxx_wp_retrieve_password_message', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: That’s correct... that’s how I’m doing it. The part I’m having trouble figuring out is how to reset it to text/plain since I don’t want the other emails sent as HTML because they don’t have line breaks, etc. when they are set to HTML.

Comment: Ok, you could try intercept it with a global variable... I updated the snippet above.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working during initial testing. I still need to test a bit more, but it’s looking good so far.

Answer (score 1):

This way works for me without setting a `$GLOBAL`:

```
function xxx_wp_email_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}

function xxx_wp_retrieve_password_message( $content, $key ) {
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'xxx_wp_email_content_type' );

    ob_start();

    $email_subject = xxx_wp_retrieve_password_title();

    include( 'templates/email_header.php' );
    include( 'templates/lost_password_email.php' );
    include( 'templates/email_footer.php' );

    $message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_message', 'xxx_wp_retrieve_password_message', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Wordpress 6.0 you can use the `retrieve_password_notification_email` to access (among other things) the headers for **only** the lost password email:

```
function set_lost_password_email_content_type(array $defaults, string $key, string $user_login, WP_User $user_data): array
{
    if (!isset($defaults['headers'])) {
        $defaults['headers'] = [];
    }

    $defaults['headers'] = (array) $defaults['headers'];

    $defaults['headers'][] = 'Content-Type: text/html';

    return $defaults;
}

add_filter(
    'retrieve_password_notification_email',
    'set_lost_password_email_content_type',
    10,
    4
);
```

The filter is called in `wp-includes/user.php`:

```
/**
 * Filters the contents of the reset password notification email sent to the user.
 *
 * @since 6.0.0
 *
 * @param array $defaults {
 *     The default notification email arguments. Used to build wp_mail().
 *
 *     @type string $to      The intended recipient - user email address.
 *     @type string $subject The subject of the email.
 *     @type string $message The body of the email.
 *     @type string $headers The headers of the email.
 * }
 * @type string  $key        The activation key.
 * @type string  $user_login The username for the user.
 * @type WP_User $user_data  WP_User object.
 */
$notification_email = apply_filters( 'retrieve_password_notification_email', $defaults, $key, $user_login, $user_data );
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't technically answer the question - but more the question behind the question. The reason you might want to set the content type only for the password reset email is that setting all system emails to `text/html` will break the default password reset email.

I suggest using the `retrieve_password_message` filter in combination with the `wp_mail_content_type` filter to make the password reset email compatible with the HTML format:

```
<?php
// adding support for html emails
// this converts ALL wp_mail emails to HTML, which messes up the password reset
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','squarecandy_set_content_type' );
function squarecandy_set_content_type() {
        return "text/html";
}

// add this filter too
// this will make the password reset email compatible with the HTML format
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_message', 'squarecandy_retrieve_password_message', 10, 1 );
function squarecandy_retrieve_password_message( $message ) {
    // Revise the message content to make it HTML email compatible
    $message = str_replace('<','',$message);
    $message = str_replace('>','',$message);
    $message = str_replace("\n",'<br>',$message);
    // make any additional modifications to the message here...
    return $message;
}
```

Otherwise, if you only want to set individual emails to `text/html`, the `$GLOBALS` method in the answer from @signal2013 also works, but might be better applied to target your *custom* email instead of to the default password reset email (leave this as the default `text/plain`).